# Sharepoint 2010 Export list to template more then 50 MB

Tags: list, migration

How could I save a list template, which can save a Elements more then 50 MB. I must export to Sharepoint 2013 a list wchich template are higgher then 50 MB. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the MaxTemplateDocumentSize property on the SPWebService ContentService.

In a SharePoint PowerShell window type"

```
$docSize = 50000000
$webservice = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$webservice.MaxTemplateDocumentSize = $docSize
$webservice.Update()
```

You might need to call these if not in a "SharePoint" PowerShell window:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration")
```

Also Check : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebservice.maxtemplatedocumentsize(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebservice.maxtemplatedocumentsize%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

This might solve your problem

Comment: And how could I call this in not a PowerShell Window ?

Comment: I am not able to find its C# equivalent. As this is only one time activity. You can do this with Powershell.

Comment: And I can do it only by Powershell. I shouldyn't do it on C# and in Visual Studio ?

Comment: Its one of the same thing. But sharepoint administrators prefer to do it with powershell script rather than custom code.